# Problem with this Ansible command to clone from Git during deployment

Tags: git, deployment, ansible

There have been lots of questions about this and I've read a lot of answers but nothing I've seen solves my situation, so I could do with some help.

When the command below to fetch the code from the git repo is executed, I get the classic error:

`Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.`

I've had this error in other situations (not Ansible) and always solved it but I'm stumped here.

The `tp10_deploy_key` private key exists and has been copied to the remote machine (to `/root/.ssh`) correctly, the matching public `tp10_deploy_key` is set up as a deploy key for the relevant repo.

But it fails, and performing a clone command manually produces the same error.

I tried moving the public `tp_deploy_key` in github from being specific to the repo to being a general authentication but it still generates and error, through both ansible or manually.

Here's the ansible command:

```
    - name: 'Repo does not exist'
      block:
        - name: Copy the repo to the remote server.
          git:
            repo: "{{ git_repo_url }}"
            version: "{{ git_repo_version }}"
            dest: "{{ drupal_core_path }}"
            separate_git_dir: "{{ git_bare_dir }}"
            force: yes
            single_branch: yes
            depth: 1
            accept_newhostkey: yes
            key_file: "{{ github_deploy_key }}"
          register: code_uploaded
      when:
        - not repo_dir.stat.exists
```

The debug shows this:

```
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git -h refs/heads/master",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "accept_hostkey": false,
            "accept_newhostkey": true,
            "archive": null,
            "archive_prefix": null,
            "bare": false,
            "clone": true,
            "depth": 1,
            "dest": "/var/www",
            "executable": null,
            "force": true,
            "gpg_whitelist": [],
            "key_file": "/root/.ssh/tp10_deploy_key",
            "recursive": true,
            "reference": null,
            "refspec": null,
            "remote": "origin",
            "repo": "git@github.com:xxx/xxx.git",
            "separate_git_dir": "/root/tp10",
            "single_branch": true,
            "ssh_opts": null,
            "track_submodules": false,
            "umask": null,
            "update": true,
            "verify_commit": false,
            "version": "master"
        }
    },
```

I'm assuming the `ls-remote` command is being used as a first stage in checking the branch exists before performing the `clone` command. (But that's just a guess.)

The ansible.cfg file contains this:

```
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

The ForwardAgent was a later addition during testing, but made no actual difference to the results with or without it.

There are a lot of other Ansible commands being run since it builds the server first, so generally the communication between my local and the server is fine. But I can't seem to make this work (though chances are it's something really simple).

Just in case it matters, I'm deploying to a DigitalOcean droplet using Ubuntu 20.04, which is what I'm using in the local development VM.

Comment: Since it also fails manually, this all looks like you (still) have an ssh key problem which will probably be more obvious by running something like `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git clone git@your.server/your/repo`

Comment: If you do have the same problem with a manual git checkout, why do you complicate  the issue by bringing Ansible in? See the **minimal** part in [mre].

Comment: I didn't "complicate it" by using ansible, it was failing in ansible so I *tested* it manually.

Comment: @Adaddinsane a question on Stack Overflow should follow the [mre]. Once you excluded that Ansible was the culprit, you should also have made your issue minimal in the question, by removing Ansible out of the equation.